# Rails query - How to joins two tables on specific columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I have a **model(OwnershipTransfer)** with `two columns` that are `belongs_to` to another **model(Account)**:

```
  class OwnershipTransfer < ApplicationRecord

   belongs_to :transfer_from, class_name: 'Account'
   belongs_to :transfer_to, class_name: 'Account'

  end
```

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord

has_many :ownership_transfers, class_name: 'OwnershipTransfer', foreign_key: :transfer_to

end
```

I am trying to `join Account and OwnershipTransfer` with a `SQL` like this

```
SELECT * FROM petalmd_development.accounts a 
join petalmd_development.ownership_transfers ot 
on a.id = ot.transfer_from_id 
where ot.meeting_event_id = 458
```

I have tried: `Account.joins(:ownership_transfer).on(Account.arel_table[:id].eq(OwnershipTransfer.arel_table[:transfer_from_id])).where(ownership_trasnfers: {meeting_event_id: 458})`

But `Delegating on to arel is deprecated` in rails 6
any clue to explicitly `select a column to JOIN ON`?

Comment: Arel is the backbone of ActiveRecord so I strongly doubt that its being deprechiated in Rails 6. Where did you get this information from?

Comment: It is not, only the delegation to join_sources from a relation is deprecated.  Arel join_sources still exists.

Comment: You are both right @max, @dbugger
running above query, I had this error : 
`ActiveSupport::DeprecationException (DEPRECATION WARNING: Delegating on to arel is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.0.`

Question modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking the parts out for clarity.

The tables involved...

```
account_table = Account.arel_table
transfership_table = OwnershipTransfer.arel_table
```

The arel join...

```
join = account_table.join(transfership_table).on(account_table[id].eq( transfership_table[:transfer_from_id] ))
```

Using the arel join in the query...

```
Account.joins(join.join_sources).where(ownership_transfers: {meeting_event_id: 458})
```

Comment: Another option is to provide the counter associations in `Account` and skip the `Arel`. e.g. `class Account; has_many :transfer_froms, class_name: 'OwnershipTransfer', foreign_key: :transfer_from_id; end` then `Account.transfer_froms` will result in the same.